# Minesweeper Counting Mines not working

Tags: java, minesweeper

So, im at the point of counting the number of nearby mines ASSUMING if the spot chosen had no mines and this is what I came up with:

```
public static int numNearbyMines( boolean [][]mines, int row, int col) {    

    int nearbyMines = 0;

    if (mines[row - 1][col] == true) {  nearbyMines += 1; }
    if (mines[row - 1][col - 1] == true) {  nearbyMines += 1; }
    if (mines[row -  1][col + 1] == true) {  nearbyMines += 1; }
    if (mines[row][col + 1] == true) {  nearbyMines += 1; }
    if (mines[row][col - 1] == true) {  nearbyMines += 1; }
    if (mines[row + 1][col] == true) {  nearbyMines += 1; }
    if (mines[row + 1][col - 1] == true) {  nearbyMines += 1; }
    if (mines[row + 1][col + 1] == true) {  nearbyMines += 1; }
    return nearbyMines;
}
```

However, I realized that this method would not work because if I chose a place such as a corner, it would be "reading" outside of the array, hence not working. How would I change this so that even if I picked a corner, it would only read inside the array?

Comment: You need to add a check if the address (like [row-1][col]) is a valid one (within bounds). This check is best done in a method.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this sort of issue is to make a function to read arrays safely.
Example:

```
boolean readMines(int x, int y) {
    if(x >= 0 && x < mines.length && y >= 0 && y < mines[0].length) {
        return mines[x][y];
    }
    return false;
}
```

This checks to make sure it's safe to read at the indices you give it before reading, and assumes there's no mines in places that can't be read. It should work for what you need.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a new method? or implemented within the method I put in above?

Comment: @BrianKang
That should be a new method somewhere in your code that you call instead of reading from the array directly.

SIDENOTE: You don't need an "== true" on if statements with booleans inside of them.

Comment: The idea is fine. The code is wrong. It will not compile.

Comment: @c0der What's the error? I can't see anything wrong with it, but maybe I'm just tired.

Comment: Test it, compile it before posting.  `return mines[x][y];` should be `return true;` . Also change the name of the method.

Comment: @c0der No it shouldn't, it's supposed to read the value at mines[x][y] IF there is a value to be read, otherwise returning false if there isn't. The purpose of the function isn't to figure out whether it's safe to read mines, it's to read mines safely.

Comment: With return value set to `boolean`?

Comment: @c0der Yes, mines is a boolean array holding whether or not there's a mine located at the indices.

Comment: OK. Sorry my mistake

Comment: @c0der It's fine, it's natural to skip over some code when you think you understand already.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check if the address (like [row-1][col]) is a valid one (within bounds). This check is best done in a method:

```
boolean isValid(int x, int y) {
    if(x >= 0 && x < mines.length && y >= 0 && y < mines[0].length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```